# How would one find the median of a set of three integers without sorting or if statements in python?

Tags: python

I figured I could obtain the middle integer by finding the Max and Min from the set leaving the remaining integer to be the median.
How can I say that the Median is an integer that is not equal to the Maximum and Minimum without obtaining just True and False statements?

```
def median3(num1,num2,num3):
    Maximum = max(num1,num2,num3)
    Minimum = min(num1,num2,num3)
    Median = int != (Maximum and Minimum)
    print(Median)
```

Comment: You need to make a set object, then remove the max and minimum. You don't need to check equality yourself

Comment: Anyways, that's not mathematically a median. It's just a number in between the max and min

Comment: I do realize that its not technically the median, this way in theory would just get me the answer I needed. We're also not allowed to import statistics either because I'm aware you can do it that way as well. Thank-you!

Comment: So, do you actually want the median, or just the third value?

Comment: Ideally the median, but it just so happens that the middle integer in this case would be the median anyways so I figured it would be easier to just obtain the middle value. A user below mentioned using import numpy but we are also not allowed to use that either.

Comment: The mathematical median of three values would be `(max + min) / 2`...

Comment: @cricket_007 No, median is the value of the data point in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, make a set object, then remove the max and minimum. You don't need to check equality

```
def median3(num1,num2,num3):
    vals = {num1, num2, num3}
    vals.remove(max(num1,num2,num3))
    vals.remove(min(num1,num2,num3))
    print(vals.pop())

median3(1, 2, 3)  # 2
median3(6, 3, 2)  # 3
median3(100, 2, 500)  # 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import median

x = [31, 41, 31]

med = median(x)
med_unique = x.count(med) == 1

print(med, med_unique)

# 31 False
```

If you can't import anything, then you can define `median` yourself:

```
def median(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n < 1:
        return None
    if n % 2 == 1:
        return sorted(lst)[n//2]
    else:
        return sum(sorted(lst)[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0
```

If you can't `sort` or use `if`:

```
def median(lst):
    return max(min(lst[0], lst[1]), min(max(lst[0], lst[1]), lst[2]))
```

Comment: Comments say numpy isn't allowed

Comment: Title says `if` statements and sorting aren't allowed

Comment: @ottomeister,  check this version.